# update tab1 set col1=col2,col2=col1

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How this query swap data of col1 and col2 of tab1 ?
Basically for swapping we need temporary variable but here we are not. so how sql server does this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just that:

```
UPDATE  tabl
SET     col1 = col2,
        col2 = col1
```

No `DML` query sees its result, to avoid [Halloween problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halloween_Problem).

Internally, an `UPDATE` lock is placed on the record (or data page), the old values are read and stored into the temp variables, then the lock is promoted to `EXCLUSIVE` and the new values (stored in temp variables) are written to appropriate columns.

Comment: Just out of interest, do you know if this works even if the isolation level is set to Read Uncommitted?

Comment: @Paul: yes is does. `DML` queries would place the locks despite the `READ UNCOMMITED`.

Answer (score 0):

My notes credit Joe Celko:

Each assignment in the `<set clause list>` is executed in parallel and
each SET clause changes all the qualified rows at once.  Or at least
that is the theoretical model.  In practice, implementations will first
mark all of the qualified rows in the table in one pass, using the WHERE
clause.  If there were no problems, then the SQL engine makes a copy of
each marked row in working storage.  Each SET clause is executed based
on the old row image and the results are put in the new row image.
Finally, the old rows are deleted and the new rows are inserted.  If an
error occurs during all of this, then system does a ROLLBACK, the table
is left unchanged and the errors are reported.  This parallelism is not
like what you find in a traditional third-generation programming
language, so it may be hard to learn.  This feature lets you write a
statement that will swap the values in two columns, thus:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET a = b, b = a;
```

This is not the same thing as

```
BEGIN ATOMIC
UPDATE MyTable
SET a = b;
UPDATE MyTable
SET b = a;
END;
```

In the first UPDATE, columns a and b will swap values in each row.  In
the second pair of UPDATEs, column a will get all of the values of
column b in each row.  In the second UPDATE of the pair, a, which now
has the same value as the original value of b, will be written back into
column b -- no change at all.  There are some limits as to what the
value expression can be.  The same column cannot appear more than once
in a `<set clause list>` -- which makes sense, given the parallel nature
of the statement.  Since both go into effect at the same time, you would
not know which SET clause to use.